# Sharepoint metadata for user

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

How can i programatically access the metadata for a  Sharepoint user like, Title and About me in Sharpoint.

I can get the SPUser but there seems to be no interface, except for LoginName, Name and email.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab user's Active Directory information, then you would need to provision User Profile Service Application to perform a periodic synchronization of the AD data to the user profile service application database.  Then the data will become available for a user account using [UserProfileManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx) and [UserProfileManager.GetUserProfile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.getuserprofile.aspx) method.

Comment: The metadata i have added is inside SP and not in AD. The reason is that the metadata is linked to list(lookup) in SP list

Comment: i still think it has to be through the UserProfileManager but would like to see how you linked that to a lookup list. I'd love to help further